# ffmpeg mov to mp4 plays fine on linux no video on windows

Tags: ffmpeg

I am using the cmd `ffmpeg -i MAG.mov -c:a aac -strict -2 MAG.mp4`

On my linux box playback video & audio is fine. On Windows there is audio only. Any idea how to fix?

Comment: Install the needed codecs for playback. But this is not a question for SO (simple check: try the all-in-one VLC).

Comment: With that command, output video codec is H.264 or MPEG-4 Part 2 which are generally installed. More likely, the pixel format isn't 4:2:0. Share the log of the command.

Answer (score 1):

Actually your question should be more like "why is the player x on my operating system y not able to play the file".

On the other hand you tagged the question "ffmpeg", so here comes the ffmpeg related answer:

```
ffmpeg -i MAG.mov -c:a aac -strict -2 MAG.mp4
```

You do not specify most possible base parameters in this command, so ffmpeg copies whatever can be copied to the output format (except the codec, this will be decided based on the extension).

Interpolating the little information you gave us i have to assume that you used windows "media player" on a windows 7 box without addtional directshow codecs installed.  If it was like this, the answer would be like "please install a h264 compatible directshow decoder and some mp4 demuxing directshow filter on your box.

If you want to guarantee the playback on windows, you best just force your output to be wmv:
ffmpeg -i MAG.mov -strict -2 MAG.wmv

Comment: *ffmpeg will decide internally if the video stream will be re-encoded or not* --> no, if video codec is not set to copy, video stream will be re-encoded. The only uncertanty is over which encoder - libx264, if linked, or the internal mpeg4 one.

Comment: True, thanks for the correction. Edited accordingly.